# Consumir Web Service do Moodle

Tags: php, javascript, web-service, rest, moodle

Estou tentando consumir o webservice do moodle, seguindo um exemplo js/rest que encontrei no github, criei um teste.php com o código abaixo (trocando o domainname e o token) porém quando chamo a página não recebo nada na variavel response, pelo chrome eu recebo um Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT dentro do server.php.

A minha idéia é consumir outra função do webservice, porém nem o exemplo simples estou conseguindo, o Moodle já está com as funções de webservice/rest ativado e tudo mais.

Algo que eu gostaria de acrescentar é que consigo utilizar o serviço pela url (abaixo um exemplo de outra função do webservice):

```
/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=meutoken&wsfunction=core_user_get_users&moodlewsrestformat=json&criteria[0][key]=departament&criteria[0][value]=1
```

Assim ele me retorna um json, porém eu precisava utilizar o $.ajax para poder manipular esses dados, no caso mostrar o nome de algum usuário utilizando um email ou outro parametro.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var domainname = 'http://yourmoodle';
    var token = 'acabec9d208978d986986g987657ffg9';
    var functionname = 'core_user_create_users';
    var serverurl = domainname + '/webservice/rest/server.php' ;
    //add params into data
    var userstocreate = [{  username: 'testusername1',
                            password: 'testpassword1',
                            firstname: 'testfirstname1',
                            lastname: 'testlastname1',
                            email: 'testemail1@moodle.com',
                            auth: 'manual',
                            idnumber: 'testidnumber1',
                            lang: 'en',
                            theme: 'standard',
                            timezone: '-12.5',
                            mailformat: 0,
                            description: 'Hello World!',
                            city: 'testcity1',
                            country: 'au',
                            preferences: [
                                {type: 'preference1', value: 'preferencevalue1'},
                                {type: 'preference2', value: 'preferencevalue2'}
                            ]
                         },
                         {  username: 'testusername2',
                            password : 'testpassword2',
                            firstname : 'testfirstname2',
                            lastname : 'testlastname2',
                            email : 'testemail2@moodle.com',
                            timezone : 'Pacific/Port_Moresby'
                         }
                     ];
    var data = {
                wstoken: token,
                wsfunction: functionname,
                moodlewsrestformat: 'json',
                users: userstocreate
                }
    var response = $.ajax(
                            {   type: 'POST',
                                data: data,
                                url: serverurl
                            }
                         );
    console.info(response);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Check your Javascript console for the "responseText" value.
</body>
</html>
```

***server.php***  (Padrão do Moodle)

```
<?php
// This file is part of Moodle - http://moodle.org/
//
// Moodle is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
// it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
// the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
// (at your option) any later version.
//
// Moodle is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
// along with Moodle.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.


/**
 * REST web service entry point. The authentication is done via tokens.
 *
 * @package    webservice_rest
 * @copyright  2009 Jerome Mouneyrac
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU GPL v3 or later
 */

/**
 * NO_DEBUG_DISPLAY - disable moodle specific debug messages and any errors in output
 */
define('NO_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);

/**
 * NO_MOODLE_COOKIES - no cookies with web service
 */
define('NO_MOODLE_COOKIES', true);

require('../../config.php');
require_once("$CFG->dirroot/webservice/rest/locallib.php");

if (!webservice_protocol_is_enabled('rest')) {
    debugging('The server died because the web services or the REST protocol are not enable',
        DEBUG_DEVELOPER);
    die;
}

$server = new webservice_rest_server(WEBSERVICE_AUTHMETHOD_PERMANENT_TOKEN);
$server->run();
die;
```

Comment: Poste o código que está em `server.php`. Se for muito grande, só coloque como é o retorno

Comment: Não sei se adianta muita coisa, mas se eu chamar as funções direto na url, passando os parâmetros eu consigo utilizar o webservice, mas na requisição ajax não.

Comment: Você vai mesmo colocar TOKEN e no javaScript? Qualquer pessoa pode ver e terá acesso ao seu moodle.

Comment: Sim, no caso real eu usaria um token para habilitar outra função, por exemplo algo para visualizar o nome de alguém, não tem problema a pessoa saber o token, esse código de "create users" eu coloquei pela estrutura mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não consegui entender porque o código em js não funciona mas consegui consumir utilizando um exemplo em php que está no mesmo repositório do exemplo em javascript.

```
<?php



$token = 'meutoken';
$domainname = 'http://meumoodle';
$functionname = 'core_user_get_users';


$restformat = 'json'; //Also possible in Moodle 2.2 and later: 'json'
                     //Setting it to 'json' will fail all calls on earlier Moodle version
//////// moodle_user_create_users ////////
/// PARAMETERS - NEED TO BE CHANGED IF YOU CALL A DIFFERENT FUNCTION
$user1 = new stdClass();
$user1->key = 'username';
$user1->value = 'myvalue';

$users = array($user1);
$params = array('criteria' => $users);



$serverurl = $domainname . '/webservice/rest/server.php'. '?wstoken=' . $token . '&wsfunction='.$functionname;
require_once('./curl.php');
$curl = new curl;
//if rest format == 'xml', then we do not add the param for backward compatibility with Moodle < 2.2
$restformat = ($restformat == 'json')?'&moodlewsrestformat=' . $restformat:'';
$resp = $curl->get($serverurl . $restformat, $params);
$json = json_encode($resp);

$obj = json_decode($resp);


?>
```

Depois é só imprimir o valor do $obj.
Nesse exemplo que coloquei como resposta estou usando outra função "core_user_get_users", mas a base é a mesma, só é necessário mudar os parâmetros conforme a documentação da API do Moodle.

Comment: Funcionando na versao 3

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema que você, mas consegui resolver observando o seu código.

O *Moodle* tem algumas condições para inserir dados nos bando que mudam de acordo com a versão da plataforma.

Por exemplo, na versão que estou usando a senha deve ter no mínimo um caractere maiúsculo e um caractere alfanumérico.

Foi essa a mensagem de erro que retornou quando utilizei parte do seu código. Então foi só mudar a senha para as condições solicitadas para funcionar.